# NHibernate - populate data from multiple stored procedures

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, nhibernate-mapping

Yeah, yet another nhibernate & stored procedures question, sorry...

I have two stored procedures which return the same structure (so I would like to bind them to the same class), the only difference is the 'where' condition in the second stored procedure. Can I bind both stored procedures to my class? How would the mapping file look like? Or would you prefer different approaches:

- use only one stored procedure and add new input parameter which says how the procedure should behave
- don't use NHibernate at all - use DataAdapter instead
- create a view (but in my example I don't know how...)
- ...

First stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [BadCodes].[GetCodesBetween]
    @codeFrom bigint,
    @codeTo bigint
as
begin
    set nocount on

    ;with BadCodesOriginal as (
        select Code 
        from Scanning.BadCodes 
        where Code between @codeFrom and @codeTo
    ),
    BadCodesScanned as (
        select Code, count(*) NumberOfBadCodesScanned 
        from BadCodes.Scan
        where Code between @codeFrom and @codeTo
        group by Code
    )
    select t1.Code Code, isnull(t2.NumberOfBadCodesScanned, 0) NumberOfBadCodesScanned
    from BadCodesOriginal t1 left join BadCodesScanned t2 on (t1.Code = t2.Code)
    order by t1.Code
end
```

Second stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [BadCodes].[GetCodesBetweenDifference]
    @codeFrom bigint,
    @codeTo bigint
as
begin
    set nocount on

    ;with BadCodesOriginal as (
        select Code 
        from Scanning.BadCodes 
        where Code between @codeFrom and @codeTo
    ),
    BadCodesScanned as (
        select Code, count(*) NumberOfBadCodesScanned 
        from BadCodes.Scan
        where Code between @codeFrom and @codeTo
        group by Code
    )
    select t1.Code Code, isnull(t2.NumberOfBadCodesScanned, 0) NumberOfBadCodesScanned
    from BadCodesOriginal t1 left join BadCodesScanned t2 on (t1.Code = t2.Code)
    where isnull(t2.NumberOfBadCodesScanned, 0) <> 1
    order by t1.Code
end
```

And this is my class:

```
public class CheckedBadCodeOverview
    {
        public virtual long Number { get; set; }
        public virtual int NumberOfScans { get; set; }

        public CheckedBadCodeOverview()
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `<sql-query>` for each SP.

Check [16.2.2. Using stored procedures for querying](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#sp_query)